How is $W = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : y - \overline{x} = 0\}$ not a subspace, but $Z = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : y - x = 0\}$ is?
Started to learn the concept of subspaces in linear algebra last week, but couldn't understand how $W$ isn't one. I know that for $W\subseteq V$ to be a subspace, it has to contain $\{0\}$, the sum of two vectors of $W$ has to be in $W$ and the condition $y - \overline{x} = 0$ must be true.
My confusion came from how $Z$ is a subspace, but $W$ is not, since the difference between the two is that $W$ is defined by the subtraction of conjugate of $x$?
The vector space is $V = \mathbb{C}^2$, $Z = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : y - x = 0\}$ is a subspace of $V$, but $W = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2  : y - \overline{x} = 0\}$ isn't a subspace of $V$.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Does your definition of subspace not include that it should be closed under scalar multiplication?

What do you mean by "the condition $y-\bar{x}=0$ must be true"?

If $\mathbb C^2$ is to be taken as a $\mathbb R$-vector space, then $W$ and $Z$ satisfy all properties of a subspace and are vector subspaces of $\mathbb C^2$. If $\mathbb C^2$ is to be taken as a $\mathbb C$-vector space, the same is not true anymore for $W$, as closure under scalar multiplication property reads "$\forall (x,y)\in W, \forall \lambda \in \mathbb C, \lambda(x,y) \in W$". Taking the example given by ultralegend5385 in comments,

$(i,−i)\in W$, but $(−1,1)=i(i,−i)\notin W$.

Thus $W$ is not a subspace of the $\mathbb C$-vector space $\mathbb C^2$.

Given a vector space $V$ over a field $K$, a subset $V' \subseteq V$ is a $K$-vector subspace of $V$ if the following conditions are satisfied:
(1) $0 \in V'$.
(2) If $v_1,v_2 \in V'$, then $v_1+v_2 \in V'$.
(3) If $a \in K$ and $v \in V'$, then $av \in V'$.
In your case, $K=\mathbb{C}$ and $V=\mathbb{C}^2$. You can check that both $Z$ and $W$ satisfy (1) and (2). However, $Z$ satisfies (3) but $W$ doesn't. Indeed, if $a=i$ and $v=(1,1)$, then $v \in W$ but $av = (i,i) \not \in W$. Therefore, $Z$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-vector subspace of $\mathbb{C}^2$ but $W$ isn't.
As a matter of fact, $\mathbb{C}^2$ is also a vector space over the field $\mathbb{R}$. You can now check that both $Z$ are $W$ are $\mathbb{R}$-vector subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^2$.
